# EmbeddedId not creating index for both varaibles

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa

I have a cart table which has a embbededKey cartId(customer,product) and additional column called quantity. When the tables are created the index is created for primarykey(customer,product) and for Fk_cart_product(for product) but is not creating for the customer foreign key.

Foreign key contrains are still created for both product and customer, its only with the index of customer class is missing.

Cart

```
@Entity
public class Cart{

@EmbeddedId
private CartId cartId;

@Column( columnDefinition="INTEGER(10) UNSIGNED")
private Integer quantity;

public Cart(CartId cartId, Integer quantity) {
    super();
    this.cartId = cartId;
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

public CartId getCartId() {
    return cartId;
}

public void setCartId(CartId cartId) {
    this.cartId = cartId;
}

public Integer getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(Integer quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}


}
```

// CartId

```
@Embeddable
public class CartId implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="product_id",columnDefinition="INTEGER(10) 
UNSIGNED",foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name="Fk_cart_product"))
private Product product;


@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="customer_id",columnDefinition="INTEGER(10) 
UNSIGNED",foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name="Fk_cart_customer"))
private Customer customer;


public CartId(Product product, Customer customer) {
    super();
    this.product = product;
    this.customer = customer;
}


public Product getProduct() {
    return product;
}


public void setProduct(Product product) {
    this.product = product;
}


public Customer getCustomer() {
    return customer;
}


public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
    this.customer = customer;
}

}
```